# Lost Account/ Wallet

Tags: wallet

Back in I want to say 2011-2013 I was working and I was tipped by a man who was all excited to show me this new form of currency. I had created an account that he had sent me coins over. Since then I have lost/ switched phones and can't remember the exact app that I had at the time. Is there any way to look up my name and email?

Comment: I feel for you, whatever you were tipped would be worth like 10x now :(. I guess there's no way to retrieve that phone? If you know the guy who tipped you...ask him for his address and search it up in blockchain.info you might be able to find where your address is. Then you just need the password if it was an online app.

Answer (score 1):

Try the mainstream wallets like Coinbase, blockchain.info, etc and see if they look familiar and try to log in.

The hard part about your situation is that it's kind of the point of the Bitcoin system. Its like cash. So in a essence a few coins fell out of your pocket at the movie theater. It's online cash.

Answer (score 1):

Two options: if you had an online wallet, maybe you could retrieve your login via e-mail or something; in case you had a software wallet, you would need access to it to retrieve the private key -- still on that second case, if it was a HD wallet (Hierarchical Deterministic) and if you have the 12-word backup you can recover it on the same software (and maybe on a different one that uses the same protocol).

-
TM